# Radio button click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `jQuery v2.0.2` and `Bootstrap v3.0.3`. I am  trying to do some operation when radio button is get selected. but it is not working of me.

Html code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="WorkspaceDivId">
    <label>Workspace</label></br>
    <input name="workspaceId"  id="essenceRadioId" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" > Essence 
    <input name="workspaceId"  id="depotRadioId" type="radio" value="2" > Depot
</div>
```

javascript :

```
$("#WorkspaceDivId input[name='workspaceId']").click(function(){
    alert('You clicked radio!');
    if($('input:radio[name=workspaceId]:checked').val() == "2"){
        alert($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: `input:radio[name=type]` are you sure?

Comment: What is this `</br>` tag you're using..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting radio button check event using following code :

```
$('#essenceRadioId').on('ifChecked',function() {
        console.log('essenceRadioId');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mixup all selectors you just need

`this.value`

```
if($('input:radio[name=workspaceId]:checked').val() == "2"){
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should

```
alert($('input:radio[name=workspaceId]:checked').val());
```

instead of

```
alert($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("input[name='workspaceId']").click(function(){
    alert('You clicked radio!');
    if($(this).val() == "1"){
        alert($(this).val());
        //$('#select-table > .roomNumber').attr('enabled',false);
    }
});
```

> see working of this code [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vm5LtakL/2/)